# typedef inside class

Tags: c++, typedef

Can`t I perform typedef inside the class?

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
    class List {
    public:
           typedef int Data;
           class iterator;
           pair<iterator,bool> insert(const Data nodeId); //<-error
    private:
    class Node {
        typedef vector<NodeId> DepList;//<-error
    };
    }
```

I get an error `missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Comment: You should always be careful to see what line the error occurs on...I added `#include <utility>` `using std::pair;` to the file and it compiled fine.

Comment: please provide complete code, information on the build and the (uncut) output of any warnings (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic ...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can.

I guess the error is on the line with the pair. Have you included the right header:

```
#include <utility>
```

Also, if you don't have `using namespace std;` or `usgin std::pair;`, you need to write `std::pair`, instead of just `pair`.

P.S. Please, don't use `using namespace std;`, especially header files.

**EDIT** Looking at your edit, you need `#include <vector>`, too.
**EDIT2**: You haven't defined `NodeId`, but you have used it for the `typedef`

Comment: >>Please, don't use using namespace std;, especially header files - why?

Comment: Because any file that includes that header is going to be `using std` - cluttering the namespace.

Comment: @Yakov - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c

Comment: <vector> is included - i justs did`t copy it

Comment: @Yakov - see my edit: you haven't defined `NodeId` and you still haven't included the `utility` header.

Answer (score 1):

It's a misleading error message. Neither `iterator`, nor `NodeId` are defined, and so can't be used in expressions.

You could work with this (making iterator a reference to a forward declared class):
      `pair<iterator&,bool> insert(const Data nodeId);`

and add a forward declaration for NodeId:
      `class NodeId;`

then do:
 `typedef vector<NodeId&> DepList;`